# ¿Alguna forma de ejecutar un archivo Python al instalar un paquete?

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicación de terminal y mi objetivo es poder empaquetarla con el modulo setuptools, hasta ahí, todo bien. Mi duda entra a la hora de querer crear una base de datos con mysql en el momento de la instalación. es decir, que al momento de instalar el paquete con "pip install [nombre_paquete]" se instale la app y se cree la base de datos que necesito para usar dentro de la app. (Aclaro: dentro de la app uso el modulo mysql-connector-python)
Entonces, hay alguna forma de ejecutar un archivo python cuando ejecuto el "pip install..etc"?